# Table containing square braces will not typeset

Tags: tables

I am trying to create a table that consists of multiple inputs containing square braces. I have done some internet research and found that most people can insert the braces by wrapping them around curly braces. However, for my case, this does not suffice.

The table code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}  
\geometry{letterpaper}
%\geometry{landscape}
%\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} 
\usepackage{graphicx}               
\usepackage{eqnarray,amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pdflscape} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\AM@pagecommandstar}{}
\define@key{pdfpages}{pagecommand*}{\def\AM@pagecommandstar{#1}}
\patchcmd{\AM@output}{\begingroup\AM@pagecommand\endgroup}
{\ifthenelse{\boolean{AM@firstpage}}{\begingroup\AM@pagecommandstar\endgroup}{\begingroup\AM@pagecommand\endgroup}}{}{} % Patch to use new option
\patchcmd{\AM@split@optionsii}{\equal{pagecommand}{\AM@temp}\or}
{\equal{pagecommand}{\AM@temp}\or\equal{pagecommand*}{\AM@temp}\or}{}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Any characters can be typed directly from the keyboard, eg éçñ
\usepackage{textcomp} % provide lots of new symibols
\usepackage{graphicx}  % Add graphics capabilities
%\usepackage{epstopdf} % to include .eps graphics files with pdfLaTeX
\usepackage{flafter}  % Don't place floats before their definition
%\usepackage{topcapt}   % Define \topcation for placing captions above tables (not in gwTeX)
% \usepackage{natbib} % use author/date bibliographic citations
\usepackage{amsmath,calc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}  % Better maths support & more symbols
\usepackage{bm}  % Define \bm{} to use bold math fonts
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{library.bib} % with extension
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
 % PDF hyperlinks, with coloured links

\hypersetup{linkcolor=red,citecolor=blue,filecolor=dullmagenta,urlcolor=darkblue} % coloured links
%\hypersetup{linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,filecolor=black,urlcolor=black} % black links, for printed output

\usepackage{memhfixc}  % remove conflict between the memoir class & hyperref
% \usepackage[activate]{pdfcprot}  % Turn on margin kerning (not in gwTeX)
\usepackage{pdfsync}  % enable tex source and pdf output syncronicity
\newcommand\scalemath[2]{\scalebox{#1}{\mbox{\ensuremath{\displaystyle t#2}}}}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \caption{My caption}
    \label{my-label}
    \begin{tabular}{llll}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{Start composition}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{End composition}     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Relative error} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Net convective flux $\frac{mol}{m^2 s}$} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{{[}0.4; 0.3; 0.3{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{{[}0.5; 0.4; 0.1{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0948}         & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-4.481e-5}                               \\
    {[}0.4; 0.3; 0.3{]}                     & {[}0.5; 0.41; 0.09{]}                   & 0.1110                             & -4.845e-5                                                   \\
    {[}0.4; 0.3; 0.3{]}                     & {[}0.5; 0.42; 0.08{]}                   & 0.13                               & -5.503e-5                                                   \\
    {[}0.4; 0.3; 0.3{]}                     & {[}0.5; 0.43; 0.07{]}                   & 0.1520                             & -5.8641e-5                                                  \\
    {[}0.4; 0.3; 0.3{]}                     & {[}0.5; 0.44; 0.06{]}                   & 0.1803                             & -6.508e-5                                                   \\
    {[}0.4; 0.3; 0.3{]}                     & {[}0.5; 0.45; 0.05{]}                   & 0.2099                             & -7.2323e-5                                                  \\
    {[}0.4; 0.3; 0.3{]}                     & {[}0.5; 0.46; 0.04{]}                   & 0.2506                             & -8.1422e-5                                                  \\
    {[}0.4; 0.3; 0.3{]}                     & {[}0.5; 0.47; 0.03{]}                   & 0.3002                             & -9.3138e-5                                                  \\
    {[}0.4; 0.3; 0.3{]}                     & {[}0.5; 0.48; 0.02{]}                   & 0.3626                             & -1.0982e-4                                                  \\
    {[}0.4; 0.3; 0.3{]}                     & {[}0.5; 0.49; 0.01{]}                   & 0.4593                             & -1.3841e-4                                                  \\
    {[}0.4; 0.3; 0.3{]}                     & {[}0.5; 0.5; 0.0{]}                     & 0.9588                             & -0.0019                                                    
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

The error that I appear to receive at multiple lines is that an extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.

It would really help my if this got fixed, thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  BTW, your code compiles fine for me with TeXLive2016 and updated pacakges, so I suspect your problem is elsewhere. Without a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that reproduces the problem it is difficult to help you.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response, Peter. I have added the packages that I am using for my document, they are a lot since it is my masters thesis I think...

Comment: I get no error from the code.

Comment: Site guidelines strongly recommend that one should wait with "accepting" an answer for several hours, and maybe even a day, after first posting a query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might prefer to use a command to layout each line, so that you save typing, and you can change layout more easily.

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}  
\geometry{letterpaper}
%\geometry{landscape}
%\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} 
\usepackage{graphicx}               
\usepackage{eqnarray,amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pdflscape} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\AM@pagecommandstar}{}
\define@key{pdfpages}{pagecommand*}{\def\AM@pagecommandstar{#1}}
\patchcmd{\AM@output}{\begingroup\AM@pagecommand\endgroup}
{\ifthenelse{\boolean{AM@firstpage}}{\begingroup\AM@pagecommandstar       \endgroup}{\begingroup\AM@pagecommand\endgroup}}{}{} % Patch to use new option
\patchcmd{\AM@split@optionsii}{\equal{pagecommand}{\AM@temp}\or}
{\equal{pagecommand}{\AM@temp}\or\equal{pagecommand*}{\AM@temp}\or}{}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Any characters can be typed directly from    the keyboard, eg éçñ
\usepackage{textcomp} % provide lots of new symibols
\usepackage{graphicx}  % Add graphics capabilities
%\usepackage{epstopdf} % to include .eps graphics files with pdfLaTeX
\usepackage{flafter}  % Don't place floats before their definition
%\usepackage{topcapt}   % Define \topcation for placing captions above     tables (not in gwTeX)
% \usepackage{natbib} % use author/date bibliographic citations
\usepackage{amsmath,calc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}  % Better maths support & more symbols
\usepackage{bm}  % Define \bm{} to use bold math fonts
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{library.bib} % with extension
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
 % PDF hyperlinks, with coloured links
\hypersetup{linkcolor=red,citecolor=blue,filecolor=dullmagenta,urlcolor=darkblue} % coloured links
%\hypersetup{linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,filecolor=black,urlcolor=black} % black links, for printed output
\usepackage{memhfixc}  % remove conflict between the memoir class & hyperref
% \usepackage[activate]{pdfcprot}  % Turn on margin kerning (not in gwTeX)
\usepackage{pdfsync}  % enable tex source and pdf output syncronicity
\newcommand\scalemath[2]{\scalebox{#1}{\mbox{\ensuremath{\displaystyle t#2}}}}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\data}[8]{[#1; #2; #3] & [#4; #5; #6] & #7 & #8 \\}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\toprule
Start composition  & End composition & Relative error & Net convective flux $\frac{mol}{m^2 s}$ \\
\midrule
\data{0.4}{0.3}{0.3}{0.5}{0.41}{0.09}{0.1110}{-4.845e-5}
\data{0.4}{0.3}{0.3}{0.5}{0.41}{0.09}{0.1110}{-4.845e-5}
\data{0.4}{0.3}{0.3}{0.5}{0.41}{0.09}{0.1110}{-4.845e-5}
\data{0.4}{0.3}{0.3}{0.5}{0.41}{0.09}{0.1110}{-4.845e-5}
\data{0.4}{0.3}{0.3}{0.5}{0.41}{0.09}{0.1110}{-4.845e-5}
\data{0.4}{0.3}{0.3}{0.5}{0.41}{0.09}{0.1110}{-4.845e-5}
\data{0.4}{0.3}{0.3}{0.5}{0.41}{0.09}{0.1110}{-4.845e-5}
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

I get no error from your code, but the problem is known: instead of `{[}` use `\relax` after `\\`.

```
[0.4; 0.3; 0.3] & [0.5; 0.41; 0.09] & 0.1110 & -4.845e-5 \\ \relax
[0.4; 0.3; 0.3] & [0.5; 0.42; 0.08] & 0.13   & -5.503e-5 \\ \relax
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest fix, in my opinion, is to replace "`\\`" with `\\\relax`" if the following line starts with a `[` symbol.

I would also like to suggest that you change the column type of columns 3 and 4, so that the numbers in the columns are aligned (horizontally) on their respective decimal markers.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\begin{document}  

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{@{}cc
       S[table-format=1.4]
       S[table-format=-1.4e1,tight-spacing] @{}}
Start composition & End composition & {Relative error} & {Net convective flux} \\
&&& {(\si[per-mode=symbol]{\mol\per\meter\squared})}\\ 
\midrule\relax
[0.4; 0.3; 0.3] & [0.5; 0.40; 0.10] & 0.0948 & -4.481e-5  \\\relax
[0.4; 0.3; 0.3] & [0.5; 0.41; 0.09] & 0.1110 & -4.845e-5  \\\relax
[0.4; 0.3; 0.3] & [0.5; 0.42; 0.08] & 0.13   & -5.503e-5  \\\relax
[0.4; 0.3; 0.3] & [0.5; 0.43; 0.07] & 0.1520 & -5.8641e-5 \\\relax
[0.4; 0.3; 0.3] & [0.5; 0.44; 0.06] & 0.1803 & -6.508e-5  \\\relax
[0.4; 0.3; 0.3] & [0.5; 0.45; 0.05] & 0.2099 & -7.2323e-5 \\\relax
[0.4; 0.3; 0.3] & [0.5; 0.46; 0.04] & 0.2506 & -8.1422e-5 \\\relax
[0.4; 0.3; 0.3] & [0.5; 0.47; 0.03] & 0.3002 & -9.3138e-5 \\\relax
[0.4; 0.3; 0.3] & [0.5; 0.48; 0.02] & 0.3626 & -1.0982e-4 \\\relax
[0.4; 0.3; 0.3] & [0.5; 0.49; 0.01] & 0.4593 & -1.3841e-4 \\\relax
[0.4; 0.3; 0.3] & [0.5; 0.50; 0.00] & 0.9588 & -0.0019
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No, not `{}`: this produces an unwanted space in the first column.